# Selecting advertisers on name, but including their parent advertisers names also

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have three tables:

Advertisers: a list of business that produce adverts, Adverts: the adverts themselves and AdvertiserChild: a table of Advertisers parents; note that this is a flat hierarchy  and a single advertiser can be listed multiple times with a parent, no inkling as to 'level' is provided they are simply 'parents'.

So, I am trying to select all of the advertisers that had ads between certain dates where their names match the users input.  The rub is that the name can also match a parent advertiser.  Let me try and phrase that differently, the user input can match the name of either the parent or child advertiser as long as the child has some valid ads between the specified dates.

I'm just having trouble conceptually in regard to getting the parent information in there:

```
SELECT     NewsPaperAd.AdvertiserID AS ADID, Advertiser.NameAbbrev AS Name
FROM         NewsPaperAd INNER JOIN
                  Advertiser ON NewsPaperAd.AdvertiserID = Advertiser.AdvertiserID
WHERE     (NewsPaperAd.PubDate BETWEEN '1/1/2012' AND '4/1/2012')
```

Ok, I think I have it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the hierarchy is defined with a ParentID or similar column in the Advertiser table. Then something like this might work:

```
DECLARE @search NVARCHAR(255);
SET @search = '%some search phrase%';

;WITH a AS
(
  SELECT a.AdvertiserID, a.NameAbbrev, Parent = p.NameAbbrev
    FROM dbo.Advertiser AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Advertiser AS p
    ON a.ParentID = p.AdvertiserID
    WHERE a.NameAbbrev LIKE @search
    OR p.NameAbbrev LIKE @search
)
SELECT ADID = a.AdvertiserID, a.NameAbbrev, a.Parent
  FROM dbo.NewsPaperAd AS n
  INNER JOIN a
  ON a.AdvertiserID = a.AdvertiserID
  WHERE n.PubDate >= '20120101'
  AND n.PubDate < '20120401';
```

Some suggestions: (1) don't change the column output name. ADID does not say the same thing to me as AdvertiserID; what is the point of the abbreviation? (2) Don't use BETWEEN for date/time range queries... while it is ok if your data type is DATE, that can't be the case in your scenario since you're using SQL Server 2005. (3) Don't use regional formatting like m/d/y for string literals. In fact I'm still not sure if your query is supposed to end on April 1st or January 4th. Depending on language and regional settings, SQL Server might get it wrong too.

Comment: My Data Type for Date is smalldatetime.